# integrating ROME library in android studio (+ is android studio tripping?)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rome

i am working with [this](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/reading-parsing-rss-and-atom-feeds-with-rome/) guide with android studio,
i added the following lines to my build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.jdom:jdom:1.1'
compile 'rome:rome:1.0'
```

and it gradle compiled it ok, but when i tried to run "debug" i got the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Program Files\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 .......
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define LJDOMAbout$Author;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

i removed the 'jdom' compile line (maybe it was already imported?), the i was able to run and debug succesfully but after running the follwing 2 lines:

```
SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes())));
```

the code ran fine, but i got the following while debugging:
[image]

very strange...
 it couldn't run toString(), i added the following line and got this mind boggling error:

[image]

it doesnt seem healthy keeping it all like this (althogh so far it works), it seems i somhow got 2 Object classes in my path or something similar.

of course i ran clean project.

whats going on here?

Comment: There is also a newer release of Rome: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rometools/rome/1.5.0 where the package has changed from 'com.sun.syndication' => 'com.rometools.rome' and it depends on jdom 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the

```
compile 'org.jdom:jdom:1.1'
```

line added the jdom 1.0 library as-well,
manually adding both jars solved the issue